# What is a "Land And Hold Short Of" light?

Tags: runways, airport-lighting

> A runway inspection found a "Land And Hold Short Of" (LAHSO) embedded light had become dislodged and had caused damage to a tyre.

http://avherald.com/h?article=4bb1964c&opt=0

What is such a light, and what does it look like?

See also [How are runway lights constructed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52998/how-are-runway-lights-constructed)

Answer (score 5):

It's an *in-pavement* (flush) light bar that indicates the hold-short for the LAHSO operations. See: [What is a land and hold short clearance (LAHSO)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3160/14897) For the FAA they are:

> FLASHING L-850A OR L-850F LIGHT FIXTURE (Source: [AC No: 150/5345-54B](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5345_54b.pdf))

A single L-850F unit in the light bar looks like this:

[image]
([adbsafegate.com](https://adbsafegate.com/product-center/airfield/runway-lighting/L-850f-inpavement-land-and-hold-short-light))

[image]
(FAA AIM) The light bars are located as indicated by the blue arrows.

I tried to find a video to show the **pulsating white** light at night when in use, but I couldn't find any. By checking Boston Logan (KBOS) on Google Earth, and zooming in at where the LAHSO hold-short lines are, the flush light fixtures can be barely seen:

[image]