# How does a departure off a runway used for LAHSO operations work?

Tags: landing, lahso

Let's say that LAHSO operations are in effect at Long Beach (KLGB). Runway 12/30 has a hold short line short of runway 8L / 26R. If an aircraft is cleared to land runway 30, and LAHSO operations are in use, I get that.

But how do operations work for departures off of runways that have a hold short line painted on the runway? If an aircraft is cleared for takeoff runway 30, is the aircraft expected to disregard the hold short line at the departure end of the runway and use full-length?

[image]
Source: [bing.com](https://www.bing.com/maps?q=long%20beach%20municipal%20airport&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=long%20beach%20municipal%20airpor&sc=8-27&qs=n&sk=&cvid=9B751FBAB36343728230A770390AA0F6)

Comment: For those of us not well-versed in acronyms: LAHSO - Land And Hold Short Operations

Comment: The same runway would be significantly shorter for takeoff than for landing, since a takeoff would not only need to be airborne by the LAHSO line, but also climb to a safe height to cross well above any crossing traffic

Answer (score 1):

The LAHSO line and [pulsating white light bar](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53527/14897) applies *only* to landing traffic (when in effect *and* when accepted).

A phraseology example is:

> ***ATC:*** "(Aircraft ID) cleared to land runway six right, hold short of taxiway bravo for crossing traffic (type aircraft)."

There is no phraseology equivalent to a departing plane that has to do with LAHSO operations. If a runway is shortened for any reason, "shortened" will be added to the taxi and takeoff clearances, but this is another matter.

[image]

When a departure is involved as shown above, it is the landing traffic that needs to land and hold short.

---

Image source, reference, and further reading: [AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap4_section_3.html)